# Error in restoring the tensorflow model and metagraph while using seq2seq and attention model.

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using seq2seq model with attention mechanism for a chatbot as given in [link](https://github.com/Currie32/Chatbot-from-Movie-Dialogue/blob/master/Chatbot_Attention.ipynb), I am able to train the model and save it but when I am trying to restore the model I am getting an error:

Code for loading the model:

```
  with tf.Session() as sess:
        #try:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/media/saurabh/New Volume/nlp_ucf/project/model/model_0.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, '/media/saurabh/New Volume/nlp_ucf/project/model/model_0.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001')
```

The error I am getting is

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_something.py", line 254, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/media/saurabh/New Volume/nlp_ucf/project/model/model_0.ckpt.meta')
  File "/home/saurabh/tfenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1577, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/saurabh/tfenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 498, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/home/saurabh/tfenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 259, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined operations.' % node.op)
ValueError: No op named attn_add_fun_f32f32f32 in defined operations.
```

I am even unable to understand the error. Does anyone have any clue about it? I was able to find one more person with a similar issue on StackOverflow but couldn't understand what exactly is the solution?